# check for date in list, validate it, replace certain values and convert it into the date object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of values, I would like to check and validate the date values, convert them from string to date object. But there is one problem some dates are like this type of string "Expected in May 2018"
I would like to replace "Expected in May 2018" to "01 May 2018" and then convert to the date object

Here is my list:

```
mylist= ['13 April 2018','Mercury','0','13 April 2018', 'October', '59','27 April 2018','Kaala','0','27 April 2018', 'Adityam','34','Expected in May 2018','XXX','99']
```

Here is my code so far:

```
for n, i in enumerate(mylist):
    if i == datetime.strptime(i, '%d %b %Y'):
        mylist[n] = datetime.strptime('12 Dec 2016', '%d %b %Y')
pprint.pprint(mylist)
```

Final output of above list should be:

```
mylist= ['2018-04-13 00:00:00','Mercury','0','2018-04-13 00:00:00', 'October', '59','2018-04-27 00:00:00','Kaala','0','2018-04-27 00:00:00', 'Adityam','34','2018-05-01 00:00:00','XXX','99']
```

Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are missing some statements like the imports, anyways there are more errors, like some date that you take as "valid" doesn't match your specified format. E.g.: time data '13 April 2018' does not match format '%d %b %Y'

Comment: If I understand the question correctly:
1. Find all valid dates in the list
2. Convert them to ISO 8601 timestamps and/or date objects
3. ???
4. PROFIT!

Comment: @Blacksilver your understanding is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 changes to be made:

1. [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) throws a ValueError if no date can be parsed, so you have to replace your `if i == datetime.strptime(i, '%d %b %Y'):` with a `try: ... except:` block:

   ```
   for n, i in enumerate(mylist):
       try:
           mylist[n] = datetime.strptime(i, '%d %b %Y')
       except ValueError:
           pass
   ```
2. Your date format is incorrect. `%b` means "abbreviated month name", but your month names aren't abbreviated. You have to use `%B` instead:

   ```
   for n, i in enumerate(mylist):
       try:
           mylist[n] = datetime.strptime(i, '%d %B %Y')
       except ValueError:
           pass
   ```
3. If you want the dates in your list formatted like "2018-04-13 00:00:00", you have to format them with [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

   ```
   for n, i in enumerate(mylist):
       try:
           mylist[n] = datetime.strptime(i, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
       except ValueError:
           pass
   ```
4. If a string starts with "Expected in", replace it with "01":

   ```
   for n, i in enumerate(mylist):
       if i.startswith('Expected in '):
           i = '01' + i[11:]

       try:
           mylist[n] = datetime.strptime(i, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
       except ValueError:
           pass
   ```

Result:

```
['2018-04-13 00:00:00',
 'Mercury',
 '0',
 '2018-04-13 00:00:00',
 'October',
 '59',
 '2018-04-27 00:00:00',
 'Kaala',
 '0',
 '2018-04-27 00:00:00',
 'Adityam',
 '34',
 '2018-05-01 00:00:00',
 'XXX',
 '99']
```

Comment: @AranFey: Its not converting all dates to '%d %b %Y' only some

Comment: @spider22 Oops, I didn't notice that. My bad. Answer updated.